# Request Mapping in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mapping, hibernate-mapping

in springMvc we can use in controllers the mapping like so

for example for `url=projectName/student/all`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {
   //...
   @GetMapping("/all")
   public String listStudents() {
   //...
  @GetMapping("/add")
   public String addStudent() {
   //...
```

I'm need to do the same thing but now I'm not using springMvc but Java EE with Hibernate, and I want to be able to call different functions based on the url, like `url=projectName/student/all` and `url=projectName/student/add`

in `StudentServlet`

```
@WebServlet("/student")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   

public ProfesseurServlet() {
    super();
}
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  // if(the the url is `projectName/student/add`)
  //do ....

  // if(the the url is `projectName/student/all`)
  //do ....
```

I've tried :

```
  String path= request.getRequestURI().substring( request.getContextPath().length() );
    if ( chemin.startsWith( "/.." )//...
```

but I've got this error

```
HTTP 404 Status - Not Found
The requested resource is not available.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: the JavaEE way to do the things similar to spring 's request mapping is to use JAX-RS implementation such as [Jersey](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/)

Comment: Exactly as the previous comment. Search for `@Path` (roughly equivalent to `@RequestMapping`) and `@GET`, `@POST`, etc.

Comment: alright thank you all